# Xen - virt-install fails

Tags: virtualization, centos, xen

I am trying to setup a Xen DomU using virt-install --prompt
After answering the usual questions the installation image is being downloaded from the internet.
Then after 'Creating storage file' and 'Creating domain' the proces ends with

Connected to domain <> 
Escape character is ^]

Then nothing happens. No booting installation kernel, no Anaconda installer, nothing.
Can anyone advise me how to overcome this?

System info: CentOS 5.8 final, runlevel 3. No Gnome installed and no intention to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at both the syslog (or "messages" on CentOS) and the libvirt log file. They will tell you what is going wrong.

If that doesn't help you, try to open up a new shell and type in the following command:
`strace -f -p <PID of the correct process>`

The strace might be able to tell you what is going on.